# XKB Keyboard Configuration on Debian system

Tags: x11, keyboard, keyboard-layout, xkb

I'm configuring my keyboard layout on Debian to learn how XKB extension works. I'm trying to load a custom keyboard layout and am not sure why it's not working in a graphically environment but is working in a virtual console.

I created a new keyboard layout file at `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/foobar` that is based on the file at `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us`. The following shows the relevant section:

```
default  partial alphanumeric_keys modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "basic" {

    name[Group1]= "English (US)";

    key <TLDE> {    [     grave,    asciitilde  ]   };
    // key <AE01> { [     1,    exclam      ]   };
    key <AE01> {    [     a,    A       ]   };
    key <AE02> {    [     2,    at      ]   };
    key <AE03> {    [     3,    numbersign  ]   };
// ...
```

You can see that I've changed the key labeled `<AE01` (the one key) from the symbol `1` and `exclam` to `a` and `A`.

I configured my system to use my custom `foobar` layout by editing the `/etc/default/keyboard` file to look like the following:

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
# XKBLAYOUT="us"
XKBLAYOUT="foobar"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS="ctrl:nocaps,altwin:menu_win"

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

When I boot my system into my graphical desktop environment and press the `1` key I was expecting it to come out like an `a` but it's not working; it's still a `1`.

What's weird is if I switch to a virtual console with the keyboard shortcut `Ctrl + Alt + F1` then I can see that my change worked and pressing the `1` key prints an `a`.

If I use the `localectl` command that it also looks like my change worked:

```
$ localectl
   System Locale: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
       VC Keymap: n/a
      X11 Layout: foobar
       X11 Model: pc105
     X11 Options: ctrl:nocaps,altwin:menu_win
```

Why isn't my custom `foobar` layout working in a graphical environment?

I've tried hunting through the twists and turns of the `keyboard-setup.service` systemd unit and found the following scripts were called:

- `/lib/console-setup/keyboard-setup.sh`
- `/usr/bin/setupcon`

I noticed that my `foobar` layout wasn't output in the `localectl list-x11-keymap-layouts` command.

The man page from `localectl` points to the following Configuration Guide:

https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/xorg-docs/input/XKB-Config.html

It does mention that we shouldn't use layouts anymore

> Keymap configuration is the way formerly used to configure xkb. The user included a special keymap file which specified the direct xkb configuration. This method has been obsoleted by previously described rules files which are far more flexible and allow simpler and more intuitive syntax. It is preserved merely for compatibility reasons and should be avoided if possible.

However I tried anyways by populating the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-foobar-kdb.conf` file with the following:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "keyboard defaults"
    MatchIsKeyboard "on"

    Option "XkbModel" "pc105"
    Option "XkbLayout" "foobar"
    Option "XKbOptions" ""
EndSection
```

After rebooting my system I cancelled out my `XKbOptions` options but still didn't successfully load my foobar map. So I'm still confused about how to load a custom layout in X11.

Comment: What happens if you issue `udevadm trigger --subsystem-match=input --action=change` when in X, (as in `man keyboard`)? Do you have any script that is sourced when your X session starts, something like `.xinitrc`? It could contain a Xmodmap action, although this seems unlikely.